# Black screen right before the login screen in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Right when I resume my Windows 7 computer from hibernation, it decides to install updates. I let it do that. So when it restarts by itself, the computer does the Windows 7 Starting Windows screen then transitions to a black screen with a cursor. Normally it stays like that for 0.3 seconds then moves on to the login screen but this time it hangs on this screen. I can move the cursor around. Once I move the cursor the screen dims. I tried safe mode and restarted a few times but all of them make me see this black screen with a cursor. I don't have restore points. Should I reinstall?